# Show that $a_n (X_n-c) \stackrel{d}{\to} F$ implies $X_n \stackrel{\mathbb{P}}{\to} c$ for any sequence $a_n \to \infty$

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, weak-convergence

I am given that $a_n\to\infty$, and $a_n(X_n-c)\xrightarrow{d}F(x)$ for some distribution $F$ and constant $c$. I am to show that $X_n\xrightarrow p c$.

What I've tried: first I thought maybe some version of Slutsky's applied here, but it seems not. Then I tried using the definitions and the fact that for any $\epsilon>0$ and $x\in\mathbb R$, we have $\frac x {a_n}<\epsilon$ for high enough $n$. But I couldn't find a way to use this.

Finally I've tried working backwards from the desired conclusion via a reductio, but that doesn't seem to go anywhere either. Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1527657/321264

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hints:** Fix $\epsilon>0$, $\delta>0$ and a function $\chi \in C_b(\mathbb{R})$ such that $0 \leq \chi \leq 1$, $\chi(x)=0$ for all $|x|<1/2$ and $\chi(x)=1$ for $|x| \geq 1$.

1. Set $\chi_R(x) := \chi(x/R)$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Show that there exists $R>0$ such that $$\int \chi_R(x) \, dF(x) \leq \delta.$$
2. Prove that $$\mathbb{P}(|X_n-c| \geq \epsilon) \leq \mathbb{P}( a_n |X_n-c| \geq R) \leq \int \chi_R(a_n(X_n-c)) \, d\mathbb{P}$$ for all $n$ sufficiently large.
3. Deduce that $$\limsup_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{P}(|X_n-c| \geq \epsilon) \leq \int \chi_R(x) \, dF(x) \leq \delta.$$ Conclude.

Comment: Thanks -- some of your notation is unfamiliar to me, though. Can you explain please what is meant by "$F(dx)$" and by "$d\mathbb P$"?

Comment: @Ceph Since $F$ is a distribution (... as you write in your question...), we can integrate with respect to it, right? $d\mathbb{P}$ is the integral with respect to the underlying probability measure, i.e. $$\mathbb{E}g(X_n) = \int g(X_n) \, d\mathbb{P}.$$

Comment: I think I see. In the way you use it, then, is there a difference between $dF(x)$ and $F(dx)$? Or are these equivalent? (I am familiar with the former but not the latter.) And are these two furthermore equivalent in your usage to $d\mathbb P$?

Comment: @Ceph Sorry for the confusion; for me these two notations are indeed equivalent. If you are familiar with the notation $dF(x)$, then you should be also familiar with $d\mathbb{P}$...? As I said, $\int \dots \, d\mathbb{P}$ denotes integration with respect to the probability measure $\mathbb{P}$.