# Show that if $x_n(X_n-X)\overset{D}{\to}{Y}$ then $X_n\overset{P}{\to}X$

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence

Let's say that we have a sequence $x_n$ of real numbers such that $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n = \infty$. I want to show that if $x_n(X_n-X)\overset{D}{\to}{Y}$ then $X_n\overset{P}{\to}X$. The problem seems quite easy if I can argue that $X_n-X \overset{D}{\to}\frac{Y}{x_n} = 0$. Now as convergence in distribution implies convergence in probability $X_n - X \overset{P}{\to}0$ and we conclude that $X_n \overset{P}{\to} X$. The issue is that I don't know whether this series of implications are necessarily true. Is this valid? If so, are there any necessary hypothesis that I am missing?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1527657/1027216

Comment: Well I'd be careful with the description. The "convergence in distribution to a ***constant*** is equivalent to convergence in probability".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We cannot write $X_n-X \overset{D}{\to}\frac{Y}{x_n}$ since the limit is take with respect to $n$.

In order to overcome this, fix a positive $\varepsilon$ and write
$$
\mathbb P(\lvert X_n-X\rvert>\varepsilon)=\mathbb P(x_n\lvert X_n-X\rvert>x_n\varepsilon).
$$
Let $R$ be a continuity point of the cumulative distribution function of $\lvert Y\rvert$. There exists $n_0$ such that for each $n\geqslant n_0$, $x_n\varepsilon>R$ hence for such $n$'s,
$$
\mathbb P(\lvert X_n-X\rvert>\varepsilon)\leqslant \mathbb P(x_n\lvert X_n-X\rvert>R)
$$
and it follows that for each continuity point $R$ of the cumulative distribution function of $\lvert Y\rvert$,
$$
\limsup_{n\to\infty}\mathbb P(\lvert X_n-X\rvert>\varepsilon)\leqslant \mathbb P(\lvert Y\rvert>R).
$$
Conclude by picking  a sequence $(R_k)$ of such points which goes to infinity (why is it possible?).